# How to give the address of jooq generators custom strategy, while loading the configuration from xml file?

Tags: java, maven, jooq

I am loading jooq configuration from a file and I have a custom generator setting like this:

```
<generator>
  <name>gen.generator.myGenerator</name>
    <strategy>
      <name>gen.generator.myGeneratorStrategy</name>
  </strategy>
.
.
</generator>
```

I am loading my strategy from a sub-project of my original project.

but the question  is, how to address my strategy? because I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Your `GeneratorStrategy` needs to be on the classpath of your code generator. This means you have to make sure you add your sub-project containing the strategy as a dependency to your project, or at least to the `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin, e.g.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <executions>...</executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-subproject-containing-the-strategy</artifactId>
            <version>${my-subproject-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas , but I am not sure if it solves my problem because I am using Programmatic generator configuration method. I use jooq API and I read my xml with Jaxb and Generate by GenerationTool, all of them written in java code. I know how to solve this problem in maven and it works but now I am confused a bit because I am not working directly with jooq codegen maven  plugin.-------------- also I can't say I am using standalone application in fact I am writing a maven plugin which one of it goals trigger my jooq generation

Comment: @frdsprtrdr: Well, the reason is the same. You don't have your own class on the classpath of whatever logic you're writing to generate jOOQ code. I don't know what you did, you didn't post your code here on Stack Overflow, so I can't help you with the specific problems you're experiencing. But you can take some inspiration in jOOQ's official Maven plugin to see how the classpath can be tweaked in a plugin: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen-maven/src/main/java/org/jooq/codegen/maven/Plugin.java